# Swift: How to add a class method in 'String" extension

Tags: swift

I want to add a class function into extension:

```
extension String {
     class func test () {
     }
}
```

I get the error: `Class methods are only allowed within classes; use 'static' to declare a static method`

Or how should i call " `String.test()`"

But for **NSString**

```
extension NSString {
    class func aaa () {
    }
}
```

no errors.

If i add **static** keyword:

```
extension String {
    static func aaa () {
        self.stringByAppendingString("Hello")
    }
}
```

Got: `Expression resolves to an unused function`,

So how should i add a class function also want to use `self.` method.

**EDIT:** This works!

```
extension String {
    static func aaa (path:String) -> String {
        return path.stringByAppendingString("Hello")
    }
}
```

but about @lan's answer:

```
mutating func bbb(path: String) {
    self += "world"
}
```

When i type it appears like this:

```
String.bbb(&<#String#>)
String.bbb(&"nihao")

Cannot invoke 'bbb' with an argument list of type '(String)'
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`Class` and `static` functions are not called on an instance of a class/struct, but on the class/struct itself, so you can't just append a string to a class.

[Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html):

> Within the body of a type method, the implicit self property refers to
>   the type itself, rather than an instance of that type.

You can, however, append a string to a variable instance of a `String` using the `mutating` keyword:

```
extension String {
    mutating func aaa() {
        self += "hello"
    }
}

let foo = "a"
foo.aaa() // ERROR: Immutable value of type 'String' only has mutating members named 'aaa'

var bar = "b"
bar.aaa() // "bhello"
```

If you are trying to use a pointer to a string as a parameter, you can use the `inout` keyword to alter the inputed string:

```
extension String {
    static func aaa(inout path: String) {
        path += "Hello"
    }
}

var foo = "someText"
String.aaa(&foo)
foo //someTextHello
```

Comment: how should i call "String.add()" ?

Comment: On an instance of a String, not on the class itself. It makes absolutely no sense calling add on the type String because there is no value to append to

Comment: hey @lan, can you check my edied question again?

Comment: @WilliamHu I think there's a fundamental misunderstanding here. What you need is an _instance_ method, not a _type_ method. This will require you to create an instance of the type that you're working on to call the method, not directly on the type itself, i.e. `let x = "str" x.someMethod()`, not `String.someMethod()`.

Comment: @0x7fffffff No i understand, i want to make a Class function in extension, but i call "append" instance method by self, which is wrong because self is Class not instance. Thanks any way!

Comment: I could not run your code with "let = foo", I needed to change it to "var = foo", FYI. Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: @Birdman the `let` example was to demonstrate that it does not work with an immutable string, hence why the error message is in the comment after it. I will make this more clear and revert the changes.

Comment: @Ian Ah yeah the comment makes it much more clear. Anyways this was really useful, so thanks!

Answer (score 4):

While correct, it's somewhat atypical to see a `mutating` member added to a `String` extension as shown in Ian's answer.  `String`s (and value types in general) are meant to be immutable so the only way to use a `mutating` method is to declare instances `var` at the call site.  Most of the time in your code you should be using `let` constants.

As such, it is much more common to extend `struct`s to return new instances.  So this is typical:

```
extension String {
    func appending(_ string: String) -> String {
        return self + string
    }
}
```

and then at the call site:

```
let hello = "Hello, "
let helloWorld = hello.appending("World!")
```

You'll note of course that I'm not using `static` at all.  That's because `appending(_:)` needs to use the current instance value of the `String` we're appending to, and `class`/`static` do not refer to instances and therefore do not have values.

Answer (score 0):

["Within the body of a type method, the implicit self property refers to the type itself, rather than an instance of that type."](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html)

Thus when you extend a type by adding a type method you can only call other type methods through `self`. If you want to call an instance method you need to create an instance and call a method on that.

Comment: Thank you, you give me the hint too.